# WPF range slider move by click

Tags: c#, wpf, slider

Thanks for reading my thread

I have a range slider, which I want to move, perhaps 3% of the total range, each time I click the track. Here is the xaml code:

```
<RSlider:FormattedSlider x:Name="powerSlider"
                                               Value="{Binding Path=PowerPosition, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
                                               Minimum="{Binding Path=PowerMin, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                               Maximum="{Binding Path=PowerMax, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                               TickPlacement="None"
                                               AutoToolTipPlacement="BottomRight"
                                               Margin="1"
                                               Orientation="Vertical"
                                               Height="150"
                                               Width="50"
                                               ToolTip="Adjust laser power"
                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                               MouseWheel="PowerSlider_MouseWheel"
                                               TickFrequency="1"
                                               Thumb.DragCompleted="powerSlider_DragCompleted"
                                               Thumb.DragStarted="powerSlider_DragStarted" >                                             
                        <RSlider:FormattedSlider.RenderTransform>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="3.0"
                                            ScaleY="1.0" />
                        </RSlider:FormattedSlider.RenderTransform>
                    </RSlider:FormattedSlider>
```

I am trying to add in xaml with:

```
Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown =" powerSlider_Clicked"
```

but it does not recognize `Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown` as a property.

With current xaml, the problem is that if I left-click on the track up, the thumb will raise but it will quickly drops to the bottom, and then it just repeating itself with that.

I am wondering how I can fill in the C# code to make it work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a standard WPF slider, there is a property called [LargeChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase.largechange.aspx) which controls the amount the slider should move when clicking the Track part.

Comment: When I click the track part, the thumb moves up but then drops quickly.

Comment: @Ono Have you removed the events handling the Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown? Try also to remove the IsMoveToPointEnabled, as this kind of defeats the purpose of the LargeChange property (this property will move the Thumb to the point of the mouse when clicking).

Comment: I am not sure if I have removed  events handling the Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown, How can I know? But I have removed IsMoveToPointEnabled for sure. SOrry, really a laymen I am.

Comment: If I add Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown ="powerSlide_MouseDown" to my xaml, it shows error, says Invalid Markup, Check the error list for more information. I am now wondering do I have a track for my slider....

Comment: Events can be defined both in XAML (such as the Track.OnMouseLeftButtonDown, Thumb.DragStarted and Thumb.DragCompleted), and in code-behind. Otherwise try and build up the slider from scratch, and add the properties one by one. Ultimately you really shouldn't need any events at all - default behaviour and bindings should be sufficient.